# NMinimize with if condition

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
    B1=(r1-x1)/δ;
    B2=a/β;
    x1=10;
    r1=15;
    β=0.1;
    δ=0.2;
    f[x]=1/(r1-0);
    w=(x1+i δ)
    r=i/EFI2
    k1=If[w>= r1,1,0]
    k2=If[w<r1,1,0]
    EFI2=k1 Integrate[x f[x],{x,0,r1}]   (a -β i) +k2 Integrate[((x1+i δ)(a -β i)+c (x-x1-i δ)2) f[x],{x,x1+i δ,r1}]+i
    tab=Table[{a,c,β,δ,r1,x1,B1,B2,k1,k2,w,r,i,#}/.#2&@@NMinimize[{EFI2,i<= a/β ,i>0},{i}],{a,0.5,10,0.5},{c,0.5,10,0.5}]~Flatten~1;
    data=TableForm[tab,TableHeadings->{None,{"a","c","β","δ","r1","x1","B1","B2","k1","k2","w","r","i","TECF"}}]
```

Is this correct way to do the numerical analysis. Any alternative way to do this as I am getting different value with this. I want to run the simulation based on the different value of "a" and "c".
Thank you

Comment: With `NMinimize[{EFI2, i <= a/\[Beta], i > 0}, {i}, MaxIterations -> 300]` no error communication and result continuously depending on parameters.